# Can not connect to WCF service from Perl API after converting ASMX to WCF

Tags: perl, wcf, soap, asmx, wcf-binding

we have a ASMX service and our client consumes it via Perl API.Currently we are in the process of converting ASMX services to WCF but our client is unable to send request to our WCF service.

When we ask our client they were saying they will simply pass data object as XML over SOAP and they don't depend upon our service proxies but in the logs we are seeing below error message.

*"The message with Action '' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver. Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding"*

Please advise how can we resolve/troubleshoot this!!!

**EDIT**

XML that client is sending to us.this is working when they are sending to our ASMX:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8">
<soap:envelope xmlns:soap="reference url" xmlns:xsi="reference url">
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema">
<SOAP:body>
<contractname xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<xml>
<foo>
<fooid>1</fooid>
</foo>
</xml>
<contractname>
</soap:body>
</soap:envelope>
```

But when i run my WCF service via WCF Test client i see below XML that test client is sending to my service..

```
<S:envelope xmlns:="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<S:Header>
<Action s: mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://tempuri.org/contractname

</s:header>
<S:body xmlns xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema">
<contractname xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<xml>
<foo>
<fooid>1</fooid>
</foo>
</xml>
</contractname> etc..
```

How can i configure my WCF so that it would accept XML which is client sending to us..

My service contract:(I have tried solution that Tom mentioned in his response in addition to that i have tried below)

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace="http://tempuri.org"),xmlserializerformat]
public interface IStockService 
{
    [OperationContract(Action=@"http://tempuri.org/GetStockValue",Name="GetStockValue")] 
    int GetStockValue(string stockSymbol);

}
```

Please not that our client is not depending on our WSDL. when this handshaking was  initially started developer from our team sent the client a sample XML request so i believe they might wrote Perl script to generate XML that exactly look like the one our team sent so should i ask them modify the script to match the current script that we are expecting.

Can i modify my service contract anyway that our service will accepts same XML that they are passing..

Comment: Can you show us the configuration you are using to define your WCF endpoint (endpoint, bindings, behaviours, etc.) ?

Comment: @hugo i cannot enter everything here but i can confirm that our service is using httpbasicbinding. unfortunately we dont have control over the configuration such as binding endpoints etc..those will be controlled at server level.our config files shouldn't have such settings..

Comment: Are you sure that your WSDL file used by your client is the same as the one generated by your WCF service?

Comment: @hugo the OP says that their client is not using the wsdl.

Comment: @Tom not using the proxy from the service doesn't mean you cannot use the WSDL to generate your own proxy client side (like in Java, Delphi, etc.). But we have the XML file sent by the client and we can compare to the WSDL provided by the service if Vicky provides it.

Comment: @hugo from what the OP says we can infer that the client is not planning on updating their client code in order to consume the new service. Therefore her challenge is to make the service look like the old service. This has nothing to do with wsdl as we must infer that the consumer is unwilling to regenerate their proxy, however unreasonable this is.

Comment: It seems we do not understand each other.  I understand the problem of @Vicky.  But if she can provide the WSDL generated by the wcf service (something like "http://myserver/myservice.svc?wsdl), we could compare the contract generated regarding the message sent to the client.  Like this, we can can see what's wrong in the WCF declaration. The goal is to change the WCF declaration to match a WSDL compatible with the soap message sent by the client.

Comment: @hugo unfortunately i can not provide my actual wsdl but i have provided the blueprint of my service interface which would generate same kind of wsdl i guess.

Comment: @Tom You said it..client is not willing to change their code..

Answer (score 0):

If your customer is not relying on metadata to consume your service then they have built a very brittle integration to your service. What did they think would happen if you changed your service?

At any rate, the first thing you can try is to expose your service over basicHttpBinding, which will create your endpoint as a SOAP 1.1 service, the same version of SOAP which asmx used.

A google search for *how to make a wcf service look like .asmx* returns many results, including this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codejunkie/archive/2008/06/12/how-to-create-a-wcf-service-for-asmx-client-without-changing-the-client.aspx

> ```
> [ServiceContract] 
> [XmlSerializerFormat(Use = OperationFormatUse.Literal, Style = OperationFormatStyle.Document)] 
> public interface IStockService 
> {
>     [OperationContract(Action="http://tempuri.org/GetStockValue", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/GetStockValue")] 
>     int GetStockValue(string stockSymbol);
>
>     [OperationContract(Action="http://tempuri.org/GetCompanyDetails", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/GetCompanyDetails")] 
>     Company GetCompanyDetails(string stockSymbol); 
> }
> ```
>
> Once we make the above changes to the WCF service interface, now the
>   client should be able to seamlessly talk to the WCF service.
>
> Couple of things to note in the process.
>
> - Usage of basicHttpBinding for the service binding
> - Removal of MEX endpoint for enabling windows authentication
> - Usage of XmlSerializerFormatAttribute to enable proper messaging format
> - Usage of Action/ReplyAction parameters to provide namespace support

**EDIT base on comments**

I noticed a potential problem with your service which manifests in your WCFClient xml:

```
<contractname xmlns="tempuri.org">
```

Should be

```
<contractname xmlns="http://tempuri.org">
```

Can you check your service definition code to make sure you are setting the Action parameter of the OperationContract correctly. In fact, can you post your service code pls?

**ALSO**: there is a deeper issue here which I think bears discussion, and it has to do with the unspoken etiquette which must exist in a relationship between a api/service provider and it's consumers.

By offering a api/service, the provider tacitly agrees, among other things, to avoid *unnecessary* or *unreasonable* breaking changes.

By consuming the service, the consumer tacitly agrees, among other things, to track and respond to *reasonable* or *necessary* change within the service.

It sounds like your consumer in this case is not honoring the "agreement". To expect the service endpoints not to ever change is an unreasonable expectation.

Although it may well be possible to change your service to fit the client, from a technical standpoint it would be much easier for the client to change to fit the service, hence service metadata like WSDL.

Comment: thanks tom for the detailed answer.i have modified service interface as per your advise then i run my service using test client then i saw difference in XML that WCF Testclient is using to call service but still when my client calls they are getting same error so i edited my post adding sample XML. Could you please take a look and advise!!!